# mkvirtualenv error :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, virtual-environment

I have installed python3.9, successfully as far as I can tell,  but get the above error when I try to use mkvirtualenv to create a new virtual environment using
**mkvirtualenv py39 --python=/usr/bin/python3.9**
I have searched on here and found various answers about distutils but can't find one specific to my problem.
I have tried reinstalling distutils to no avail.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I circumvented the problem by using conda to create my virtual environments